# Blackberry Map Field is Blank?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, dictionary

So ive added a mapfield to my page. It creates everything you'd expect. ie. you can drag it around. But there is just a white bitmap instead of an actual map!

```
MapField map = new MapField();
add(map);
```

or

```
RichMapField map = MapFactory.getInstance().generateRichMapField(); 
add(map);
```

What have I done wrong?

I have it connected to Wifi. This happens on simulator and real device.

SDK 7.0 JavaME running on 9860.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your actual device provisioned with BlackBerry Internet Services, if not I don't believe you will be served with any mapping data. See Options->Device->Advanced System Settings->Service Book

Comment: Yes. Believe it or not, you have to have a Data plan even if you are trying to use the wireless. I borrowed a SIM from a friend, and that has registered my handset with the wireless network.(got a verification text message from Blackberry). Now its registered I no longer need the SIM. It is all working now :)